# Accessing the child AnchorPane of a Tab instance

Tags: java, javafx

When using the JavaFX editor, if you create a new `Tab` in a `TabPane`, it will come with an `AnchorPane` as a child.

[image]

I guess that, programatically, if you create a new `Tab` instance, the same thing occurs (it will come with an `AnchorPane` instance as a child).

```
Tab tab = new Tab("Untitled *");
```

I am trying to access such `AnchorPane`. It was my understanding that one way to do so would be getting the list of children nodes of the tab, like

```
tab.getChildren();
```

But there is no such method.

So my question is essentially,

- Do `Tab` instances come with an `AnchorPane` child when created programmatically?
- How can I access the child `AnchorPane` of a `Tab` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do Tab instances come with an AnchorPane child when created
>   programmatically?

No...

> How can I access the child AnchorPane of a Tab instance?

The node contained in the tab is called its `content`. Programmatically, you set it with

```
Tab tab = new Tab("Untitled");
AnchorPane tabContent = new AnchorPane();
tab.setContent(tabContent);
```

Of course, you don't need to use an `AnchorPane`: you can use any node you like. Most times, you'll use some kind of `Pane`.

You can similarly retrieve the content with

```
Node tabContent = tab.getContent();
```

And of course, if you're using FXML, you can assign an `fx:id` to the content of the tab, and retrieve it in the controller in the usual way.